# "Adobe Reader" plugin for <embed> tag in html

Tags: php, html, css, acrobat

How to add "Adobe Reader" Plugin for EMBED tag ? In browsers like "safari"  tag from HTML showing the message as- "Missing Plug in". I don't want to add the "flash player" plugin, I want the Adobe reader plugin only.

[image]

This is the error am getting on Safari Browser. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.pdfobject.com/

> PDFObject is an easy-to-use method for dynamically embedding PDF files
>   into HTML documents. It uses JavaScript to generate and inject a
>   standards-friendly  element into your HTML file.